# How to debug a (possible) RTL problem?

Tags: delphi, debugging

I'm asking this because I'm out of good ideas...hoping for someone else's fresh perspective.

I have a user running our 32-bit Delphi application (compiled with BDS 2006) on a Windows 7 64-bit system. Our software was "working fine" until a couple weeks ago. Now suddenly it isn't:  it throws an Access Violation while initializing (instancing objects).

We've had him reinstall all our software--starting all over from scratch. Same AV error. We disabled his anti-virus software; same error.

Our stack tracing code ([madExcept](http://www.madshi.net)) for some reason wasn't able to provide a stack trace to the line of the error, so we've sent a couple error logging versions for the user to install and run, to isolate the line which generates the error...

Turns out, it's a line which instances a simple TStringList descendant (there's no overridden Create constructor, etc.--basically the Create is just instancing a TStringList which has a few custom methods associated with the descendant class.)

I'm tempted to send the user yet another test .EXE; one which just instances a plain-vanilla TStringList, to see what happens. But at this point I feel like I'm flailing at windmills, and risk wearing out the user's patience if I send too many more "things to try".

Any fresh ideas on a better approach to debugging this user's problem? (I don't like bailing out on a user's problems...those tend to be the ones which, if ignored, suddenly become an epidemic that 5 other users suddenly "find".)

EDIT, as Lasse requested:

```
procedure T_fmMain.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
      //Logging shows that we return from the Inherited call above,
      //then AV in the following line...
  FActionList := TAActionList.Create;
  ...other code here...
end;
```

And here's the definition of the object being created...

```
type
  TAActionList = class(TStringList)
  private
    FShadowList: TStringList;              //UPPERCASE shadow list
    FIsDataLoaded : boolean;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
    procedure DataLoaded;
    function Add(const S: string): Integer; override;
    procedure Delete(Index : integer); override;
    function IndexOf(const S : string) : Integer; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TAActionList.AfterConstruction;
begin
  Sorted := False;              //until we're done loading
  FShadowList := TStringList.Create;
end;
```

Comment: If you know the line it crashes on, could you post that line of code? Do you have threads in your program?

Comment: by "instances" I think you mean "creates". Right? Does it fail on startup?

Comment: @Lasse: No secondary threads have been started before the code fails. @David:  Yes, I mean "creates", and yes, it fails on startup (during an AfterConstruction call while creating the main form).

Comment: I'd get a run of the application at the customer site using depends.exe (Dependency Walker) to see if any DLLs are being injected into the process by third-party apps on the machine.

Comment: Would you be able to see the dll injections using WinDbg and a transcript from that or via sysinternals procmon? Sounds like a new feature to ask for from MadExcept - DLL Inject guard... :-)

Comment: Why don't you call `inherited` in `TAActionList.AfterConstruction`? Sure that's not your problem, but it kind of jumped out at me!

Comment: @Warren P: dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) has a built-in debugger which just monitors module load events. It's available in the "Profile" menu, logs full paths of modules loaded etc., hooks in to GetProcAddr etc. For this kind of problem (something dependent on an environment change), it's where I'd start. If no luck there, then probably procmon.

Answer (score 5):

I hate these kind of problems, but I reckon you should focus on what's happening recently BEFORE the object tries to get constructed.

The symptoms you describe sound like typical heap corruption, so maybe you have something like...

- An array being written to outside bounds? (turn bounds checking on, if you have it off)
- Code trying to access an object which has been deleted?

Since my answer above, you've posted code snippets. This does raise a couple of possible issues that I can see.

**a: AfterConstruction vs. modified constructor:**
As others have mentioned, using AfterConstruction in this way is at best not idiomatic. I don't think it's truly "wrong", but it's a possible smell. There's a good intro to these methods on [Dr. Bob's site here.](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi4/d4constr.htm)

**b: overridden methods Add, Delete, IndexOf**
I'm guessing these methods use the FshadowList item in some way. Is it remotely possible that these methods are being invoked (and thus using FShadowList) before the FShadowList is created? This seems possible because you're using the AfterConstruction methods above, by which time virtual methods should 'work'. Hopefully this is easy to check with a debugger by setting some breakpoints and seeing the order they get hit in.

Comment: Good thoughts. Some other objects are created during a TForm.Create override by the main form. I can disable the creation of those objects to see if that then let's us get past the currently-offending line; which as you suggest would be a clue. I think bounds checking is off in the release version, so yes, I can enable that to look for problems. No objects have been deleted at that stage of the app's startup.

Comment: You have the latest madexcept?

Comment: Try using FastMM (latest version from the SourceForge) and defining CheckHeapForCorruption.

Comment: @gabr - Yes, turning on CheckHeapForCorruption occurred to me after reading Roddy's comment. I'll do that in a build going out to the user on Monday morning.

Comment: I guess the B) is a potential root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

***Our software was "working fine" until a couple weeks ago... suddenly become an epidemic that 5 other users suddenly "find".) :***

Sounds like you need to do some forensic analysis, not debugging: You need to discover what changed in that user's environment to trigger the error. All the more so if you have other users with the same deployment that don't have the problem (sounds like that's your situation). Sending a user *'things to try'* is one of the best ways to erode user confidence very quickly! (If there is IT support at the user site, get them involved, not the user).

For starters, explore these options:

***)** If possible, I'd check the Windows Event Log for events that may have occurred on that machine around the time the problem arose.

***)** Is there some kind of IT support person on the user's side that you can talk to about possible changes/problems in that user's environment?

***)** Was there some kind of support issue/incident with that user around the time the error surfaced that may be connected to it, and/or caused some kind of data or file corruption particular to them?

(As for the code itself, I agree with @Warran P about decoupling etc)

Comment: +1 Yes, an app working fine and then starting to fail out-of-the-blue, usually means something in the app's environment has changed. For things to check (with the IT support person) I'd also include checking for any newly installed software / versions / patches etc.; and changes in memory and swapping video/network cards. These could mean the software now loads at a slightly different address and is falling over uninitialized memory whereas before it was lucky to always get a spot in "zeroed out" memory.

Comment: I've sat the user in a dark room for several days, tied into a hard chair and with a bright light shining in their eyes, interrogating them about what may have changed in their system...they know nothing. Yes, I've gotten an IT pro involved on their end, but they haven't been able to determine specific system changes. One of the problems is that our app is one the user runs daily, so they don't really pinpoint when the problem begain. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Prior comment should read "our app is **not** one the user runs daily...".

Comment: @Majan - yes, I agree - could be a latent bug that surfaced because of environmental changes... but if so, it SHOULD BE reproducable.

Comment: @Mark - it's not the user you need to tie to the chair... Is this effect reproducable at all on any other system? If you have a latent bug you should be able to force it to the surface in any environment by carefully reviewing and tracing through your code.

Comment: @Majan - if it was a question of 'lucking out', in most cases the problem will only surface sporadically - it sounds like in this case it's  consistent behavior. But the app not in everyday use makes it harder. Again, I contend that a latent bug can be forced to the surface in any environment with good debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** override `AfterConstruction` and `BeforeDestruction` methods in your programs. They are not meant for what you're doing with them, but for low-level VCL hacking (like reference adding, custom memory handling or such).

You should override the `Create constructor` and `Destroy destructor` instead and put your initialization code here, like such:

```
constructor TAActionList.Create;
begin
  inherited; 
  // Sorted := False; // not necessary IMHO
  FShadowList := TStringList.Create;
end;
```

Take a look at the VCL code, and all serious published Delphi code, and you'll see that `AfterConstruction` and `BeforeDestruction` methods are never used. I guess this is the root cause of your problem, and your code must be modified in consequence. It could be even worse in future version of Delphi.

Comment: First, the assertion that "[these] methods are never used" is totally wrong. Also the nature of `AfterConstruction` is very clearly specified, so no concerns with "future version of Delphi". `AfterConstruction` is rarely used because it is seldom necessary, but it does serve 2 specific purposes: 1) It's useful when you want to take the same action after any of multiple constructors was used to create an object. 2) More importantly, it's the only way to ensure that what you are doing occurs _after_ the construction code of any subclasses.

Comment: I will concede that one should rather not use `AfterConstruction` unless it is absolutely necessary, and that your proposed `TAActionList.Create` is better (including removal of `Sorted := False`). However it is most certainly not "the root cause of [the] problem"; and this change won't even fix it because the code is logically equivalent.

Comment: I agree with Craig:  until demonstrated otherwise there is nothing wrong with using `AfterConstruction` in the way I have used it. (Since when has it been illegal to override a public virtual method?) In fact, for many years (with no problems) I have often overridden AfterConstruction for the very reason Craig states:  to have some activity occur after the chain of Create constructors has finished executing. As for the Sorted := False, you're correct...that should simply be an Assert in this case.

Comment: @Craig: Of course, it's your code, do as you want. But as you states, the code shown in the question is not at all concerned by the 2 exceptional use of AfterConstruction. We all agree that those methods are to be used for hacking purpose. A well design OOP won't need it.

Comment: @Mark: You can also override the `NewInstance` "public" virtual method. But I hope you know what you are doing. ;)

Comment: @Craig: I'm not so certain about your 2 reasons. 1) should be replaced by calling the Create in all overloaded/reintroduced constructors, and put your common code in this Create. 2) Could be done elsewhere in the code. A well designed OOP won't need it. Just like a singleton. But it's all trolling subject I guess..

Answer (score 2):

Clearly there is nothing suspicious about what `TAActionList` is doing at time of construction. Even considering ancestor constructors and possible side-effects of setting `Sorted := False` indicate there shouldn't be a problem. I'm more interested in what's happening inside `T_fmMain`.

Basically something is happening that causes `FActionList := TAActionList.Create;` to fail, even though there is nothing wrong in the implementation of `TAActionList.Create` (a possibility is that the form may have been unexpectedly destroyed).

I suggest you try changing `T_fmMain.AfterConstruction` as follows:

```
procedure T_fmMain.AfterConstruction;
begin
  //This is safe because the object created has no form dependencies 
  //that might otherwise need to be initialised first.
  FActionList := TAActionList.Create;

  //Now, if the ancestor's AfterConstruction is causing the problem, 
  //the above line will work fine, and...
  inherited AfterConstruction;

  //... your error will have shifted to one of these lines here.
  //other code here
end;
```

If an environment issue with a component used by your form is causing it destroy the form during `AfterConstruction`, then it's the assignment of the new `TAActionList.Create` instance to `FActionList` that's actually causing the AV. Another way to test would be to first create the object to a local variable, then assign it to the class field: `FActionList := LActionList`.

Environment problems can be subtle. E.g. We use a reporting component which we discovered requires that a printer driver is installed, otherwise it prevents our application from starting up.

You can confirm the destruction theory by setting a global variable in the form's destructor. Also you may be able to output a stack trace from the destructor to confirm the exact sequence leading to the destruction of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Things to do when MadExcept is NOT Enough (which is rare, I must say):

1. Try Jedi JCL's JCLDEBUG instead.  You might get a stack traceback with it, if you change out MadExcept for JCLDEBUG, and write directly the stack trace to the disk without ANY UI interaction.
2. Run a debug-viewer like MS/SysInternals debugview, and trace output things like the Self pointers of the objects where the problems are happening.  I suspect that somehow an INVALID instance pointer is ending up in there.
3. Decouple things and refactor things, and write unit tests, until you find the really ugly thing that's trashing you. (Someone suggested heap corruption.  I often find heap corruption goes hand in hand with unsafe ugly untested code, and deeply bound UI+model cascading failures.)

Comment: Have you ever come across a situation where JCLDEBUG produces a stack trace and madExcept can't?  I would be surprised.

Comment: "Decouple things and refactor things...". Yeah, that's the way I am headed. By asking the question I am trying to gather some fresh perspectives on things to try/look at when I head down that path, and getting a lot of good answers. I need to do this as efficiently as possible with respect to "wearing out my welcome" with the end user:  for some reason they don't seem as thrilled as we are to install/run multiple debugging builds aimed at solving a problem.<g>

Comment: @Mark - even if decoupling and refactoring doesn't fix the bug, it will make it much easier to test and debug, both for this bug and others.

Comment: @David - Yes because JCLdebug can work even when the VCL and all Application/Form objects and their message pumps, are no longer functional.